# How should I ask a question so that it won't be deleted by a robot?

Tags: discussion

I recently joined stackexchange to seek help, but is it allowed to ask questions at will? I have asked several questions, all of which were deleted by the review robot. Where is the administrator of this website located? What about real people? I believe this system has many flaws. Although the original purpose was to prevent spam, it is too strict, and normal questions are also deleted. I suggest that the website administrator upgrade the content review robot and be more flexible.

Comment: This question belongs to meta. Reviewers are not bots but humans. If your question gets closed, it will be reopened after you have edited in the required missing parts which are needed to make it answerable. This is not a disussion forum, this is a Q&A site.

Comment: I do see quite a few questions getting closed. All that I see getting closed, get closed for good reason. For example, this question shouldn't be here, it should be on meta.

Comment: A question getting "closed" means no answers can be added. It may get re-opened when someone votes to do so, often after an edit mending a problem with the question - the latter being the cause for closing it.

Comment: What is your example of a question that shouldn't be closed? Looking at your profile, you have asked one question, which was closed due to lack of information. You haven't edited the question or added more information when asked for it. Three humans looked at your question and agreed it lacked the information for it to be answerable (four, if you include me).

Comment: toplink - You said that you have "*asked several questions*" but as mentioned already, using *this* account, you have only asked one (before the invalid question on the main site, which was migrated to become this question here on Meta). There was a previous *answer* deleted as spam, but you said *questions* so I'll focus on that for now. Did you post those questions using a different account? If so, please link to that account (or give that username) and I'll look at the history there.

Comment: What people aren't telling you are your questions reflect lack of research and effort, you just have ideas and you want people to "write you a book" on the subject to fill these huge knowledge gaps.  Fill them yourself with coursework of your own choosing e.g. Sparkfun, Adafruit etc.

Answer (score 3):

> How should I ask a question…?

Each SE site has its [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - heed it.

([How do I ask a good SO question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

> is it allowed to ask questions at will?

Yes, given that your question is [on-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and within the scope of the site. Also avoid too broad or subjective questions asking for opinions, as described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions need to be specific. Good questions also include schematics, datasheets or other such details when applicable.

Be aware that if you ask too many poorly-received questions, you will eventually get handed an automated question ban which is difficult to recover from.

All of this serves to preserve a high quality of content on the site(s).

---

> all of which were deleted by the review robot

There is no such thing. Questions can be put on hold by other users or moderators, waiting for you to improve them with the remarks left behind to you when this happened. You can edit the question to make it appropriate and it will then get placed under re-open review, which is also carried out by other users and moderators.

There *is* a bot ("Roomba") which eventually comes to actually delete such closed questions after a few weeks of no activity.

> Where is the administrator of this website located? What about real people?

The network is owned by a private company based out of NY, USA. However, company employees do not really moderate the sites directly, it is all handled by volunteers. Either trusted users who have earned various privileges by participation, or moderators who were elected by the community. Moderators have a little diamond and the text "mod" next to their user name. All of which are real people - bots do not close posts.

> Although the original purpose was to prevent spam

No, there is no such thing. The only anti-spam counter measurement present is that you won't be allowed to post comments before you reach 50 reputation.

---

Overall when stumbling into the front door of a new community, it is advisable to hang out for a bit to see what culture there is and how the site works, before starting to assume all manner of things. The [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) are good places to start.

Comment: Yeah? I'm just looking for help, I hope I can give some references, if I already know the problem very well, I think I have almost found the answer, so sometimes some questioners themselves don't have a very comprehensive understanding of the problem.

Comment: @toplink The bottom line is that the question must be answerable. So the more you can narrow down the problem, the better. Questions of the nature "how do I do this whole project" will be too broad for this Q&A format site, they may be more suited for traditional forums.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the volunteer administrators.
You can contact us re any question or answer (yours or other people's) by clicking the "flag" button below each post.

Your pogo pin post was closed as spam by the system as it linked to your own company site.   I left a longer comment on the closed answer which hopefully you can see. Please advise if you cannot see it. I'd consider that marginal as far as spam goes as the answer was useful and relevant. Flag the question using the"flag" button below the answer if you wish to comment to the admins.

Your bicycle computer question was closed by vote of 3 site members. The reason was provided. I have also left a comment there on your question. If you improve the question as suggested it may be able to be reopened.

You play Go? :-)